# What is the difference between &b and b ?(b is and declared like this: int *b)

Tags: c++

I was trying to find out how exactly * and & are working.

I already read about this things but i couldn't really find why is &b and b have 2 different addresses. Also i don't know what is the difference between b and k (what properties each of them has). I saw that they are working in the same way.(if you modify one of a, b or k they all are gonna modify)

```
int a = 2;    
int *b = &a;    
int &k = a;    
cout << k << endl;// 2    
cout << *b << endl;// 2    
cout << &b << endl;// address 1    
cout << b << endl; // address 2    
a = 10;    
cout << k << endl;// 10    
cout << *b << endl;//10    
cout << &b << endl;//address 1    
cout << b << endl;// address 2    
*b = 20;    
cout << k << endl;// 20    
cout << *b << endl;// 20    
cout << &b << endl;// address1    
cout << b << endl;// address2    
k = 30;    
cout << k << endl;// 30    
cout << *b << endl;// 30    
cout << &b << endl;//address1    
cout << b << endl;//address2
```

I was expecting that b and &b would have the same address

Comment: `&b` is the address of the pointer variable that is b. `b` is the value of the pointer. They would have the same address if you did `b=&b;` which the `b` pointer would point to itself.

Comment: you mean if you declare a pointer it will have 2 addresses one for the pointer which is &b and one for the value which is b ?

Comment: A pointer is no different from any other variable in that it has an address.

Comment: now i understand. Thank you. Also i don't know what is the difference between b and k (what properties each of them has). I saw that they are working in the same way.(if you modify one of a, b or k they all are gonna modify)

Comment: If you have a business card b, with an address written on it, in your pocket, then &b is your pocket but your pocket is not the address on the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between &b and b ?

`b` is an expression. More specifically, it is an id-expression. The identifier `b` names a variable. The type of the variable is `int*` i.e. pointer to an integer. The result of an id-expression is an lvalue.

`&b` is an expression. More specifically, it is an addressof operation. Addressof operator `&` is unary i.e. it has one operand. Here, the operand is the id-expression `b`. The result of addressof operation is a prvalue. The returned value will be the address where the lvalue operand is stored. The type of the value is `T*` where `T` is the type of the opreand. In this case, the result type will be `int**` i.e. pointer to a pointer to an integer. Addressof operator is the inverse of the indirection operator `*`.

> I was expecting that b and &b would have the same address

There is no reason to expect that. `b` points to `a`, while `&b` points to `b`. Since `b` and `a` are separate objects, they have separate addresses as well and correspondingly the values `b` and `&b` must be different.

The only situation where `b` and `&b` could point to the same object is:

```
void *b = &b;
```